# How to use css first-child with :not()

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

There is a parent `div` with `id = "cooldiv"`. It has many `div` elements inside. Now I need to set a css property to all the child `div`-s except the first one.

So, this is what I've tried so far to accomplish this task:

```
#cooldiv .row:not(first-child) {
    top: -50px;
}
```

But, of course, it didn't work out. What's wrong here? This is the screenshot of the source code:

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try `#cooldiv .row:not(:first-child)`. It seems you missed `:` before `first-child`. Maybe that's why it doesn't function?

Comment: yeah but still not works

Comment: What do you mean? The selectors itself should work fine. But you for sure have more code there, so your styles `top:-50px` may be rewritten. Also, `top:-50px` will not work per se - the element should be positioned (relative, absolute etc.) You might need to use `margin-top:-50px` instead. It is hard to say more since very small part of your code is exposed here.

Comment: ok ok it works here :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that

```
#cooldiv .row:first-child {
    top:0px;
} #cooldiv .row {
    top:-50px;
}
```